# Adding a thumb to simplecart js

Tags: javascript, simplecart

I'm using a shopping cart js plugin called simplecart. Im having trouble getting a tumb of the product image to appear with the product info in the cart.

This line gets the full sized image to appear in the cart

```
<img src='$file' class='item_thumb' alt='{$row['name']}' />
```

Does anyone know how to get a thumb to display in the cart instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are height and width attributes available to use in `<img></img>` tags, but this will just scale the image to the size you specify in browser.

```
<img src='$file' class='item_thumb' height='20px' width='20px' alt='{$row['name']}' />
```

You may also consider adding constraints for height/width into the css of the `'item-thumb'` class you are already using.

Comment: Thats  line is from my product.php file. Adding a height and width constratin it in that file. Adding the class item_thumb sends the image to cart.php. But i dont know how to constrain the image in that file. The plugin lacks decent examples and demos!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="shop-item-image">
<img src="image/bqt-item.png" class="item_thumb" thumb="image/bqt-item.png">
</div>
```

You need to add 'item_thumb' class to the image of a product and add attribute 'thumb' with value of an image source